# two counts in the same row

Tags: count, pivot, row, pvts

is't possible to set 2 counts in the same row.
my result from query is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAsHx.png)

and i will that the end result seem like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFe5C.png)
and at the end build the precent count1 to count2

my attempt trough case was not successful : SELECT Date,Shift , CASE description WHEN 'Defects' THEN count ELSE 0 END AS Defect_Count , CASE description WHEN 'Total' THEN count ELSE 0 END AS Total_Count FROM ("Queries union)

Comment: What dbms are you using? Oracle, mysql or mssql?

Comment: i'm using mssql (2012)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
MYSQL:
select
    t.dates, t.shift,
    sum(case when t.description = 'Defects' then t.counts else 0 end) as `Defects`,
    sum(case when t.description = 'Total' then t.counts else 0 end) as `Total`
from (
    select *
    from tbl ) t
group by t.dates, t.shift
order by t.dates, t.shift

ORACLE:
SELECT dates, shift, defects , total
FROM
(
  SELECT *
  FROM tbl
)  
PIVOT
(
  sum(counts)
  FOR description IN ('Defects' as defects, 'Total' as total)
)  
ORDER BY dates

Result:
dates       shift Defects  Total
2018-01-20  AM      21     56
2018-01-20  PM      19     54
2018-01-23  AM      16     58
2018-01-23  PM      20     45
```

Answer (score 0):

many Thanks is working for the first Step (counts in the same Row).

i will try now to build the percent (Defects to Total).
Thanks.

to build the percent (defects to Total): 
  `select dates,shift,defects,total,round((100*defects/total),2) Percent2Total  from(select t.dates, t.shift,
    sum(case when t.description = 'Defects' then t.counts else 0 end) as 'Defects',
    sum(case when t.description = 'total' then t.counts else 0 end) as 'Total'
from (
    select *
    from tbl ) t
group by t.dates, t.shift
)q order by dates,Shift`.
may be it's possible to build that only with Pivot or?